# Gmail API - Scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using a service account and domain wide delegation described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and I am able to get all emails from all email accounts on that specific domain. The scope that I am using is

> https://mail.google.com/

Is there any way that I can exclude some email accounts (for example admin email accounts) from the whole domain? Is there a different procedure in order to achieve this?

To further clarify what I mean here is an example of what I want to do:

the service account will be able to access example_a@domain.com , example_b@domain.com but **not** admin@domain.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to remove access to some accounts when doing domain-wide authorization with service accounts. It's all or nothing. If your security requirements forbid direct access to some portion of domain accounts you'll need to use regular OAuth 2.0 authentication, not a service account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jay. Please correct me if I am wrong. Based on this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 all other methods other than 'service account' require user login & consent. Is this correct?